# Convert a 1D array to 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a program where I have to read the values from a textfile into an 1D array.I have been succesfull in getting the numbers in that 1D array.

```
m1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

but I want the array to be

```
m1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting them?

Comment: @brbcoding the subarray must contain 3 elements

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce((r,e,i)=>(i%3?r[r.length-1].push(e):r.push([e]))&&r,[])`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use this code :

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    
const newArr = [];
while(arr.length) newArr.push(arr.splice(0,3));
    
console.log(newArr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JbL3p/

Answer (score 7):

```js
Array.prototype.reshape = function(rows, cols) {
  var copy = this.slice(0); // Copy all elements.
  this.length = 0; // Clear out existing array.

  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      var i = r * cols + c;
      if (i < copy.length) {
        row.push(copy[i]);
      }
    }
    this.push(row);
  }
};

m1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

m1.reshape(3, 3); // Reshape array in-place.

console.log(m1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top:0; max-height:100% !important; }
```

Output:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Q2V/2)</kbd>

Comment: How to generalize this kind of "reshape" function so that it can reshape a one dimentional array to more than two dimensional array? I.e. an (1x24) array can be reshaped to (2x12), or (2x3x4), or (2x2x2x3), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could do something like this... Just iterate over the array in chunks.

```
m1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

// array = input array
// part = size of the chunk
function splitArray(array, part) {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += part) {
        tmp.push(array.slice(i, i + part));
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.log(splitArray(m1, 3)); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

Obviously there is no error checking, but you can easily add that.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sasesuka/1/edit?js,console)**

Answer (score 1):

There are *so* many ways to do the same thing:

```
var m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var n = [];
var i = 0;
for (l = m.length + 1; (i + 3) < l; i += 3) {
    n.push(m.slice(i, i + 3));
}
// n will be the new array with the subarrays
```

The above is just one.