# JavaScript array views

Tags: javascript, arrays

Via XMLHttpRequest I have received arraybuffer of Uint32 values

```
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; 
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    pointsArray = new Uint32Array(arrayBuffer);
```

However, I know that this array has an internal  structure.
Say, pointsArray length is 10 but I know it contains 5 points X,Y coordinates.

How can I create( **hopefully without copy** ) two new 'views' at this pointsArray so that I can
index X and Y points separately?

Something like:

```
var xArray = something (pointsArray)
var yArray = something else (pointsArray)
```

Then, even if pointsArray length is 10, my new two arrays will have a length of 5 so I can index them from 0 to 4.

**EDIT**: 
The question is imprecise. It implies that original input array can't be modified so the answer by David Alvarez is correct, despite the stated preference for avoiding any copies, which, in turn, for the best performance may require the format of the input array to be modified.

Comment: loop through it and turn into whatever format you want ?

Comment: I can loop but that means I have to make extra calculations on indices/elements sizes. If JavaScript has an approach without me doing it, I would like to know about it. Also, I am not clear, even if I do that, that I won't incur unnecessary copies when I create two separate arrays for X and Y. Basically, I would like not to have to create two new arrays in code via for loop construct, if possible.

Comment: What is the structure of the array ? [x1,y1,x2,y2] or [x1,x2,y1,y2] ?

Comment: [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, ...]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464605/convert-a-1d-array-to-2d-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create functions.

```js
const xArray = () => pointsArray.filter((element, index) => index % 2 === 0)
const yArray = () => pointsArray.filter((element, index) => index % 2 !== 0)
```

In that manner, no values will be copied or processed until you call `xArray()` or `yArray()`. That is what I think is the closest to a "view".

## EDIT

If you want to use that "view" to directly access nth element:

```js
const nthX = (n) => pointsArray.filter((element, index) => index % 2 === 0)[n]
const nthY = (n) => pointsArray.filter((element, index) => index % 2 !== 0)[n]
```

Then call nthX(2) if you want the x at the index 2 (of the array contianing all the x's)

## EDIT 2

If you want the same behavior without copying the array you can do:

```js
const nthX = (n) => pointsArray[n*2]
const nthY = (n) => pointsArray[n*2+1]
```

Comment: Where do I specify index when calling xArray or yArray?

Comment: You do not specify it. You just call xArray(), this will call pointsArray.filter(filterFunction). And filterFunction has this shape : function filterFunction(currentElement, indexOfCurrentElement) { // the element is returned if the function returns true }. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax

Comment: And here I directly passed the function returning even indexes for x and not even indeses for y (as you can see with the modulo)

Comment: I don't get it. How do I get x coordinate of a point at index 3, for example?
Say I have code like var x3 = something What is something in this case?

Comment: No, xArray() is an array containing all your x's. If you want to use the 3rd x, then call `xArray()[2]`

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. However per docs it creates a new typed array so there is a copy implied.

Comment: Yes but why do you want to absolutely avoid copy ?

Comment: Cause I am worried because I have too many elements in the original array to start with, so making 2 new copies of x,y subarrays is worrysome.
However, since I haven't conditioned an answer on that (just made the non-copying answer preferred) your answer is correct and works. Thank you.

Comment: Look at my edits I made a version without copy :) @Tony

Comment: While I have a feeling :) that the other answer may be more performant, I can't deny this is so far the most correct answer, given the question. I'll accept it after giving it some time to maybe someone else chime in.

Answer (score 2):

If there are 5 consecutive X coordinates and then 5 consecutive Y coordinates, you can create arrays on the same buffer:

```
let xArray = new Uint32Array(arrayBuffer,0,5);
let yArray = new Uint32Array(arrayBuffer,5*4,5);
```

(where 4 could be `Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT`)

But otherwise you will have to copy elements around, at least inside the array.

Side note: TypedArrays use platform-native byte order, so generally you can not avoid dealing with all data elements, at least in a conditional branch swapping bytes if necessary, or you can use [`DataView.getUint32(bytOffset,littleEndian)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint32) and you are back on the starting field, accessing elements individually.