# How to convert simple array into three-dimensional array (matrix) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, vue.js

Imagine I have an array:

```
DATA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
```

And I want it to convert into 3-dimensional Array((Matrix of ROW x COLUMN)x SET by Number of Instances, like this:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9];
B =  [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]];
C = [[19, 20, 21], [22,23]]
```

Note, that rows and columns of the matrix are changeable. Meaning that the number of items in the rows or column may change and even the amount of items in the data set may also differ.

I want to be able iterate through those sets of arrays into sets that a contained within particular defined classes when they are created.

EXPECTED RESULT: (GENERATED TABLE includes html structure):

```
<CONTAINER>
//A SET
<div class "set">
   ROW 1: <row><div class "items"> 1 </div><div class "items"> 2</div><div class "items"> 3</div></row>
   ROW 2: <row><div class "items"> 4</div><div class "items"> 5</div><div class "items"> 6</div><row> 
   ROW 3: <row><div class "items"> 7</div><div class "items"> 8</div><div class "items"> 9</div></row>
 </div>
</div>

//B SET
<div class "set">
       ROW 1: <row><div class "items"> 10</div><div class "items"> 11</div><div class "items"> 12</div></row>
       ROW 2: <row><div class "items"> 13</div><div class "items"> 14</div><div class "items"> 15</div><row> 
       ROW 3: <row><div class "items"> 16</div><div class "items"> 17</div><div class "items"> 18</div></row>
     </div>
    </div>

//C Set
<div class "set">
           ROW 1: <row><div class "items"> 19</div><div class "items"> 20</div><div class "items"> 21</div></row>
           ROW 2: <row><div class "items"> 22</div><div class "items"> 23</div></row>
         </div>
        </div>



</CONTAINER>
```

**Solution to this question can be found here: [Vue.js - How to convert a simple array to dynamic NxNxN Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837931/vue-js-how-to-convert-a-simple-array-to-dynamic-nxnxn-matrix/58838429?noredirect=1#comment103971035_58838429)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert simple array into two-dimensional array (matrix) with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492385/how-to-convert-simple-array-into-two-dimensional-array-matrix-with-javascript)

Comment: `3-dimensional` ....  `N x M` .... I count only two dimensions in NxM

Comment: Your question is quite confusing, think therefor you haven't solved it by yourself first place. You gotta be accurate, so: the Number of columns may change, in each `.set` row you have additional 3 rows always (or not?), than your Display is totally confusing - how did you come to order A(1), A(2), A(4), A(5), A(7), A(8)???

Comment: @roottraveller - No that doesn't help. That is only a 2D array and if you haven't noticed (based off the name and layout of the question) i tired structuring this question off that Stack overflow post.

Answer (score -1):

This is transforming to 3d array

```
const chunk = (arr, number) => {
   const chunked = arr.reduce((res, value, ind) => {
      if (ind % number === 0) {
         res.push([])
      }  
      res[res.length - 1].push(value)
      return res
   }, [])

   const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1]
   let empty = last[last.length - 1]
   if (Array.isArray(empty)) {
      empty = new Array(empty.length).fill(null)
   } else {
      empty = null
   }
   while(last.length < number) last.push(empty)

   return chunked
}

const _2d = chunk([7, 4, 2, 3, 9], 2)
console.log(_2d)

const _3d = chunk(_2d, 2)
console.log(_3d)
```