# From simple array to 2D array using reduce (ft. logical AND &&)

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, reduce, logical-and

I needed to "convert" a simple flat array into a 2D array and I went on SO to see what it has to say about the argument.
I tried to recreate the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838921/14170686), and I got this error:

```
console.log(array.reduce((twoDArray, n, i) => (i % 3 == 0 ? twoDArray.push([n]) : twoDArray[twoDArray.length-1].push(n)), []));
                                                                                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

The problem was that I didn't add `&& twoDArray` at the end of the arrow function. Here you can see:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

// this works
console.log(array.reduce((twoDArray, n, i) => (i % 3 == 0 ? twoDArray.push([n]) : twoDArray[twoDArray.length-1].push(n)) && twoDArray, []));

// here the second push() throws an error
console.log(array.reduce((twoDArray, n, i) => (i % 3 == 0 ? twoDArray.push([n]) : twoDArray[twoDArray.length-1].push(n)), []));
```

Now I don't understand a couple of things, namely:

- how does this `&& twoDArray` works? what's its purpose?
- how can this addition fix the error when it is placed only **after** the `push()` that generates the error. Shouldn't the code throw an error before to reach the `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is needed because `push` returns the new length of the array - but the accumulator needs to be *the array*, not the length.

Without the `&&`, and indenting the code into multiple lines to make it clearer what's going on, the second code is equivalent to:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// here the second push() throws an error
console.log(array.reduce((twoDArray, n, i) => {
  return (i % 3 == 0 ? twoDArray.push([n]) : twoDArray[twoDArray.length - 1].push(n))
}, []));
```

Same as:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// here the second push() throws an error
console.log(array.reduce((twoDArray, n, i) => {
  return (
    i % 3 == 0
      ? twoDArray.push([n])
      : twoDArray[twoDArray.length - 1].push(n)
  );
}, []));
```

Now, the problem should be clear: no matter which condition is entered, the callback evaluates to

```
  return (
    i % 3 == 0
      ? someNumber
      : someNumber
  );
```

because `.push` evaluates to the new length of the array.

Adding `&& twoDArray` to it makes the callback look like:

```
  return (
    i % 3 == 0
      ? someNumber
      : someNumber
  ) && twoDArray;
```

therefore returning `twoDArray` instead of the number.

> Shouldn't the code throw an error before to reach the &&?

It does. The error is thrown on the *second* iteration, when `twoDArray[twoDArray.length-1]`, when `twoDArray` is a number, evaluates to `undefined`, so it can't be pushed to. But the problem that `twoDArray` is a number instead of an array results from the code at the tail end of the prior (first) iteration: the lack of the `&& twoDArray;`.

Code like this is extremely confusing. Try not to condense code into a single line if it makes it unreadable. Another issue is that `.reduce` arguably isn't appropriate when the accumulator is the same object on each iteration. Consider instead doing something like this:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const twoDArray= [];
array.forEach((n, i) => {
  i % 3 == 0
    ? twoDArray.push([n])
    : twoDArray[twoDArray.length - 1].push(n);
});
console.log(twoDArray);
```

And use `if`/`else` instead of the conditional operator:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const twoDArray= [];
array.forEach((n, i) => {
  if (i % 3 === 0) twoDArray.push([n])
  else twoDArray[twoDArray.length - 1].push(n);
});
console.log(twoDArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and the suggestions! I think I finally got how `reduce` works.